# CSS select input by class

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I've tried to find some way to select all form inputs by class.

```
<form action="" class="registerForm">
   <input type="text" name="loginInput" class="registerInputField">
   <input type="email" name="emailInput" class="registerInputField">
   <input type="password" name="passwordInput" class="registerInputField">
   <input type="password" name="confirmPasswordInput" class="registerInputField">
   <input type="submit" value="Register">
   <input type="submit" value="Cancel">
</form>
```

I've tried: `

```
input.registerInputField{}
.registerForm > input[type=text]{}
input[type=text].registerInputField{}
```

I read a few topics related to this, but it didn't work.
I'll be glad for showing me some source or a book where I can find the answer.

Comment: `HTMLElement.getElementsByTagName('input')`

Comment: @AdrianSolarczyk: You're not wrong, but that's JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every one of the examples you gave work. Without more context, such as whether you're using Angular which adds in scoping that might be relevant, it's impossible to say why you might experience it not working. But this clearly works:

```css
input.registerInputField {
   background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="registerForm">
   <input type="text" name="loginInput" class="registerInputField">
   <input type="email" name="emailInput" class="registerInputField">
   <input type="password" name="passwordInput" class="registerInputField">
   <input type="password" name="confirmPasswordInput" class="registerInputField">
   <input type="submit" value="Register">
   <input type="submit" value="Cancel">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: @Devin Burke Great